# "generic-garbage-collector" deleted StatefulSet and its pods. Why?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

The `generic-garbage-collector` deleted our `StatefulSet` `prometheus-k8s` and eventually also the corresponding pods. Which resulted in a ~5min outage of our monitoring system as all 3 pods were deleted *at the same second*.

Why did the `generic-garbage-collector` do this? What can it be?

The `StatefulSet` has this owner-reference which should stop deletion from garbage-collector (see [K8s doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/garbage-collection/)):

```yaml
metadata:
  ownerReferences:
  - apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
    blockOwnerDeletion: true
    controller: true
    kind: Prometheus
    name: k8s
    uid: 68631aa0-e528-11e9-8769-42010a8400bf
```

I.e. it is created & controlled by the [prometheus-operator](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator).

Kubernetes/GKE cluster version: `1.19`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was triggered due to control plane downtime on 2021-05-24 17:03 PDT, which restarted the cluster master and forced the system to check each of the objects in the system to see if their owner is missing and rebuild that graph.

In case the problem happens again, the system will mitigate it automatically and it will provide more information to compare both incidents and try to find a root cause.

The best outcome is to migrate to [1.20.x](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/65200#issuecomment-729220961) where the problem is already fixed for sure.